# When is a Sheet in SwiftUI re-created?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does anyone have any idea when the closure of `.sheet` is supposed to be re-rendered? Should it really be doing so whenever anything in the whole `body` causes an update even if it’s not remotely in the hierarchy?

For example, where `cartItemModal` is a `@State` property not being updated:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            theCartView
            // even putting the sheet outside of the cart view entirely, it still gets re-rendered
            Text("").sheet(item: $cartItemModal) { (productWithCartItem) -> QuickAddView in
                QuickAddView(viewModel: QuickAddViewModel(productDetails: productWithCartItem, cartAPIProvider: self.cartAPIProvider))
            }
        }
    }
```

Controls in my modal can update data in the underlying list driving `theCartView`. The data doesn't actually affect my `QuickAddView` modal, which has been rendered with it's own struct. Yet that closure is called again and my modal is re-rendered.

---

Adding a full sample here:

https://gist.github.com/sprynmr/66811b088ac50d9f297471d5c70d0eb3

---

I think my question boils down to: What about transient `@State` properties in views unrelated to the underlying data change, or driven via operators like `.sheet`. If those are going to be recreated at any time when anything in the `body` is updated than a lot of folks will probably struggle with their transient view state getting reset.

Consider a timer firing that grabs updates from the server and updates a list that a `.sheet` is being displayed from. The sheet will be recreated and `@State` will be reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI Views are value types. Modifying them in any way creates a new View, just like modifying an Array creates a new Array. But SwiftUI Views are just data. They don't represent the actual thing displayed on the screen like UIViews. After re-computing the View hierarchy, SwiftUI computes the differences and applies that to its internal state, and renders any changes (which may involve animations).

This means that anything you compute in a `body` closure must be fast, because you should expect it to be evaluated many times. It should also generally be lazy if possible, to avoid recomputing it if it's not actually necessary. (Constructs like `ForEach` and `List` are lazy in this way.)

It's also critical that computing a View does not generate any side-effects, and not rely on global state. You don't control when it will be evaluated, so your Views must rely only on SwiftUI data (such as the state, environment, and values passed directly to the View).

Comment: Maybe my question is very specific to the Modal with the `Binding<Identifiable?>`. Since that is driving by a `@State` property, when the cart data updates, my sheet is recreated with the now stale value in that property. Do I need to also update the `@State` whenever cart updates? Perhaps that's the answer here.

Comment: By "re-render" do you mean the sheet goes away and comes back? Or that it changes what element is displayed? Or something else?

Comment: Most narrowed down concept: I have a sheet currently presented. That sheet has some temporary state held in a `@State` property that changes as the user interacts with it. Think quantity in my example. Then something in the view hierarchy my `.sheet` is attached to is updated, maybe via a background timer process, but no data the sheet itself uses. This is causing the sheet view to be re-created, and blowing away any temporary state.

Comment: I see. My issue was that the state I was storing in the `QuickAddView` was not stored in a `@State` property, but was a view model on a normal property. Normal properties get blown away, but `@State` do not.

Answer (score 2):

Your sheet doesn’t get rerendered, but it does get re-evaluated every time anything  that your sheet is bound to is mutated. This is expected behaviour.